# Retry Ajax Request 5 Times with 1 Second Interval

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a verify.php file that will check a database entry and return 1 if it exists or 0 if it doesn't. But this database will get updated between 0 to 5 seconds. So for at least the first 5 seconds the return might be 0.

In another page, I want to check the verify.php's return with AJAX and retry for 5 times with 1 second interval between each checks. If at any time in that 5 second check, it received 1, exit the checking loop and display success message.

I have written this but it only checks once and I don't know how to make it check x amount of times:

```
<p id="status"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = 'verify.php';
$('#status').text('Please wait...');

$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:url,
    success: function(msg){
        if (msg == 1){
            $('#status').text('success');
        }else{
            $('#status').text('failed');
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Turn your AJAX call into a function
- Have a variable that tracks how many tries you have
- Call your AJAX function in its own callback  with a delay of one second if needed, that is, you haven't exhausted your tries and your status is wrong.

Code

```
var tries = 0;    
function getStatus() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    success: function(msg){
      tries++;
      if (msg == 1){
         $('#status').text('success');
      } else {
          if (tries >= 5 ) {
            $('#status').text('failed');
          } else {
             setTimeout(getStatus, 1000);
          }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without writing the code for you, here is a "brute-force" approach ...

wrap your ajax call in a function
declare a "can stop" and a times-called variable outside that function
every time the function is called, increment the times-called variable
set the "can stop" variable inside your ajax response code

create a function that looks recursive; 
it checks for the "can stop" variable and bails once it's set
it calls your ajax function
it checks the times-called variable and bails if the count is passed
it calls setTimeout to call itself;

use window.setTimeout (or the ajax wrapper for it) to wait for a second

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.setInterval(function , timeInMillis)` function to time your ajax queries. Use a boolean to check when a particular query has returned.

Only when it has returned should the timer make a new query.

Wish you the best.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var queryOn = false;
       var interval;
$(function (){

    var attempts = 0;
    interval = window.setInterval(
                    function () {
                        if (queryOn === false) {
                            queryOn = true;


                            var url = "...url";

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: url,
                                success: function (msg) {

                                    queryOn = false;
                                    if (msg === 1) {
                                        $('#status').text('success');
                                        window.clearInterval(interval);
                                    } else {
                                        $('#status').text('failed');
                                    }


                                    if(attempts === 5){
                                         window.clearInterval(interval);
                                    }
                                    ++attempts;
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 5000);

});





        </script>
```